# Fatal error while doing segue between viewcontrollers

Tags: uitableview, swift, uiviewcontroller, segue

I am getting fatal error during segue from one view controller.

magicNumber is Integer variable
MagicNo is Label in second view controller

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if segue.identifier == "start"
    {
        var secondScreen = segue.destinationViewController as! SecondViewController

        secondScreen.magicNo.text = String(magicNumber)

    }
}
```

error is here on this line below

error is :

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

```
secondScreen.magicNo.text = String(magicNumber)
```

Comment: This question is certainly a duplicate.  You can't assign to the outlets in the destination view controller because they aren't set up yet.  Put your string into a property variable in your destination view controller, then move it into the label in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [fatal error when prepared to segue to view controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28640685/fatal-error-when-prepared-to-segue-to-view-controller)

Comment: There's no where near enough code here to diagnose this.  Either `magicNumber` is `nil`, or `magicNo` is `nil`.  Neither of those are set or defined in the code provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is `secondScreen` embedded in a UINavigationController? If so, you'll have to do something like this:

`let secondScreen = (segue.destinationViewController as? UINavigationController)?.viewControllers[0] as? SecondViewController?`